# When trying to set an HTML element's content to an Emoji in javascript, it displays strange symbols

Tags: javascript, html, emoji

I want to have a javascript function that changes the text of an element with the id "emoji" to the laughing emoji.

```
function changeEmoji() {
    document.getElementById("emoji").textContent = ""
}
```

but when I use this code the element displays `ðŸ¤£` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add emoji by using their unicode id http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f600

for smiley laungting it's code 0x1F923

```
var emoji = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F923)
```

Be careful, String.fromCodePoint() is part of the ES2015 standard.so you can have issue on some old browsers

```js
var emoji = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F923)
document.getElementById("emoji").textContent = emoji;
```

```html
<div id="emoji">
</div>
```